# Selenium running Chrome does not behave the same as in real Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, html-parsing

I'm using Selenium to render webpage and then do content extraction. However, I found what selenium returns is different from what I get use Chrome DevTools.

The python code I use is simple:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() #.PhantomJS()

driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Basically, I found the field I'm looking at does not show up from Selenium results most of the time. It does work sometimes, but most of the time, it just does not render what a real Chrome browser does. I'm using Mackbook Pro.

Comment: So what's your question? You don't have any details on what you are trying to do or an actual statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`page_source` only gives you what you would get if you right clicked and hit `View Page Source` which is what the original document was. Anything loaded dynamically via javascript, etc will not be in that. If you want it all in selenium you can do:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: Thanks! It works much better! One thing I found is, if I re-run the job many times, it sometimes return correct results while sometimes not. I was thinking of site throttling but if I just browser and keep refresh, it does not happen.